# Customize the 'Default', 'New' and 'Edit' aspx web part without Share Point or Infopath

Tags: javascript, ms-access, sharepoint

Currently i'm developing a page in Sharepoint 2010 for my team's requirement, i have an individual sharepoint site in my working area, however sharepoint designer and info path applications are restricted to use, so i couldn't change or customize the default form for add, edit or view.

I linked my ms-access table with sharepoint, it has around 20+ fields. If i open the list item, it shows all fields which is not required at all times or for all users.

**Below is my requirement:**

1. Customize the fields (form should display only the specific fields)
2. Submit or Save button should capture the current system time
3. Have to lock few fields for users to edit accidentally or
   intentionally

**It can either be in VBA (.vbs) or Javascript(.Js) file.**

Any help regarding this is very much appreciated...

Comment: What have you tried?  What specifically isn't working?  Show some code, preferably an MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Specifying the `ShowInNewForm`, `ShowInEditForm`, and `ShowInDisplayForm` properties

Every SPField object has properties that specify whether it should be displayed in the default new, edit, and display forms.

There are multiple ways to set these properties, a few of which are detailed below.

### 1. Custom Server-side Solution (C# or VB.net) built by a developer

I've seen organizations develop a relatively simple custom SharePoint solution (created through Visual Studio) that provides an interface accessible from the List Settings menu to toggle the [`ShowInNewForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showinnewform(v=office.14).aspx), [`ShowInEditForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform(v=office.14).aspx), and [`ShowInDisplayForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showindisplayform(v=office.14).aspx) properties on fields within any list.

In my opinion, this is the best solution since once it's set up it allows end users to control the visibility of the fields without any coding or special tools.

However, it requires the most up-front investment from your organization's SharePoint developers, if you have any.

### 2. PowerShell run from a web server by a server administrator

Your SharePoint administrators can also set those three properties manually using PowerShell from any of your SharePoint farm's web front end servers, if they'd rather do it as a one-time fix than as a reusable solution.

```powershell
$web = get-spweb "http://your/web/url"
$list =  $web.lists["Your List Title"]
$field = $list.fields["Your Field Title"]
$field.ShowInNewForm = $false
$field.ShowInEditForm = $true
$field.ShowInDisplayForm = $true
$field.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

### 4. JavaScript run from a web browser by a site owner

And in truth, you have access to these properties too. You can set them using JavaScript which you can execute from the console tab in the F12 developer tools.

These properties can be set by updating the `SchemaXml` property of the SPField object. If you retrieve the XML first, you can then add the properties to the XML, as in the code below.

```js
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext');
var listName = "Your List Title"; // <-- replace with actual list title
var fieldName = "Your Field Name"; // <-- replace with actual field title
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var field = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName).get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
clientContext.load(field);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){ // onSuccess
        var schemaXml = field.get_schemaXml();
        schemaXml = schemaXml.substring(0,schemaXml.length-2) 
          + 'ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" />';
        field.set_schemaXml(schemaXml);
        field.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
    },
    function(sender,args){ // onError
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Note that the properties do not exist in the schema XML by default; they're only present once they've been specified. If the properties already exist, the code above will not quite work, since it just inserts the properties to the end of the existing XML string.

You can manually view the current XML string by running code up to `field.get_schemaXml();` and then determine the desired XML string yourself.

## Alternative Approach

### Manipulating the forms with JavaScript/HTML/CSS/jQuery

If you open the new, edit, or display form in a new window (not in a modal dialog box) you can edit the page. You can then insert web parts directly onto the page.

Adding a content editor web part onto the page (below the existing list form web part) will allow you to insert HTML, JavaScript, and CSS to manipulate the page further.

To prevent SharePoint from overwriting your JavaScript and "correcting" your HTML/CSS in a content editor web part, you can add your HTML code fragment to a text file, upload the text file to a document library on the site, then set the content editor web part's Content Link property to be equal to the URL of your uploaded text file.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response, i think the Alternative Approach will work out for my scenario. I have a list named "overtime Tracker" with fields as follows "Name", "Date", "Login Time", "Logout Time", "Duration - calculated field", "Team Name - dropdown field". Save button should capture the current system automatically in the hidden field called "updated", i believe the Modified field captures his, but i require in different field. Can you please suggest a Javascript code and html code to design a form accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take this and make a formal request to your IT department. You need an application made, and from my past professional experience you're going to need an Excel file that's connected to a SharePoint list to create/read/update/delete content. It's a big undertaking, and when I did it 5 or so years ago it took 2 months. If you don't have much experience with SharePoint lists, VBA or just programming in general you're in for a rough ride.